# PostgreSQL: Can a role or user be created that is allowed to create databases, but only with specific names?

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions

Use case:

I have a web app which drops and recreates a test database on every test run.  I'd like to have it do this with a PG role which is not a superuser, and not one which can destroy or create any database willy nilly, but rather, just be allowed to drop and create a specific database name, such as foo_test.  Is this possible?

Comment: hm, doesn't seem like something you'd be able to do w/ PostgreSQL itself (although i'd love to be proven wrong); but you could enforce in the application layer. i found this ( http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2003-06/msg00212.php ) about limiting the length of database name, but nothing specific to the name yet...

Comment: Well, I believe I've done this before in a previous version of PostgreSQL, but it was so long ago, that I forget how it's done.  It had to do with using globs or masks somehow in a GRANT statement, or such.  So that a user could create "prefix_*" databases only.

Comment: I would be satisfied with restricting database creation to a schema or namespace, if that's the only way.

Comment: If your fear is unintentionally damaging an existing (production) database, i'd say: use a different machine (VM) for testing purposes. If that is impossible: create a separate instance on the same machine using a different portnumber. If that is impossible, use a reserved databasename, and allow the test process to do everything with it, including drropping it. Don't allow it to connect to other databases (or create databases). The testing process can just create and drop (cascading) a schema of its own. A separate(cron)script could even drop&create the test databases, including authorisation

Comment: BTW: if you compile & install Postgres from source, there is a nice option "make test", which runs regression tests on a temporary database, which is created and dropped on the fly. Maybe you could borrow something from these scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function with the "SECURITY DEFINER" option that creates the database and sets permissions on it. It would need to be in a database the restricted role could connect to of course.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html

You might be able to do it all with an SQL function, but it's trivial with plpgsql.

Comment: That wouldn't work, because CREATE DATABASE cannot be called inside a transaction, and a function always run inside a transaction. There's even a specific error message for that: `CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`

Comment: Damn - that complicates things. I've gotten used to pretty much all the DDL playing nicely with transactions. That means you'd have to go outside the DB for at least the CREATE DATABASE. You could maybe loop out and back in with dblink or call a script form pl/perlu or some such but that's not so elegant.